Is there a way to keep secure boot on and use my second monitor?
I have a Lenovo Legion Pro 5 with 2 2TB NVMe SSDs installed. One is dedicated to Windows 11, and the other is dedicated to Ubuntu latest version. Everything for Ubuntu works just fine, but when I turned secure boot on my external monitor stopped working. I tried a few different threads here at the forum but they did not work. I would prefer to keep secure boot on so I can have the most secure laptop possible. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

If secure boot is on, you will have to self-sign any proprietary drivers (like nvidia) and ensure you are running the signed kernel, grub and shim (default these days I think). Check that your linux packages don't have "unsigned" in their name.  Search this site for answers for how to self-sign modeules.
